# Can I use advanced regex pattern search in Google search?

Tags: google-search, regex

I tried to find results that match pattern such as `Apple\s*,\s*[a-zA-Z]+` but it only returned unnecessary data like regex or etc..
I needed only results like such as "Apple, Samsung".
Maybe I can do it by custom search api?